# online backup solution with api for desktop

Tags: api, backup, dropbox

I made a small backup application that simply creates an archive out specified files and folders. Now I need an online service to backup that online. Which service can i use that can be integrated into my app ?

Options I considered:

dropbox is ideal, but they have all but [abandoned the desktop](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=37565).

skydrive has no api.

I couldn't find any free reliable backup service that uses ftp .

anything else ? it should provide 1-2 gb of free space and be reasonably reliable.

Thanks

My app is in C#, but can be ported to any other language as well..

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Amaxon's S3 seems more fitting but that's not free.

Depending on your target audience, you can create a local archive and have that picked up by your regular backup solution. You might try [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/),or [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/). Expand Wuala by adding your own space. Spideroak is free up to 2GB (more if you invite friends), and also provides a good alternative to Dropbox (if you want to see how to migrate from dropbox to spideroak see my [blogpost](http://rolfje.com/2011/07/03/1355/) about that).

Answer (score 0):

Try box.net, now known as box.com or simply Box

reference: http://developers.box.com/docs